# Generating big files with Struts2 + Freemarker

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, freemarker, flush

I need to dump data into a big xml (50 ~ 500 Mb) using `Struts2` and `Freemarker`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<documents>
    <#list collection as document>
        <document>
        ...
        </document>
        <#if document_index % 100 == 0> 
           <#flush/>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</document>
```

Since `collection` can be huge, it already implements an internal logic to fetch partial data, consume it and fetch again as long as there are data available.

The problem seems to be related with the buffer of the XML: occasionally the application crashes (`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`).

A Freemarker `flush` is called every 100 documents but I don't know if the flush actually occurs, according to the [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_flush.html) it is only an indication for the embedding software (`Strut2` + `Tomcat7`).

Any suggestion on how to force flushing?

JVM disposes of about 1~2 Gb of heap memory, maybe is just a matter of memory?

Maybe `org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager` can be tuned properly for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

The problem resides in the Struts2 [`FreemarkerResult`](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.24/org/apache/struts2/views/freemarker/FreemarkerResult.java#FreemarkerResult) and how this class let you handle the flush of the output writer.

Basically if you are using `TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER` as exception handler (as I do) the whole template is processed *before* any flush is executed. (this is the desired behaviour because if there is any template error you want an exception to be thrown and handled at a higher level before any output is sent to the response)

But `TemplateExceptionHandler` is a fixed configuration embedded in `FreemarkerManager` and cannot be switched for the needs of a given request.

I decided the extend `FreemarkerResult` rewriting the method `doExecute(...)` to include a parameter that force the standard *flushing-during-template-process* for a single request even if the global configuration is `TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER`.

Comment: I submitted the proposed alternate code with a more detailed explanation here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4749

Answer (score 1):

Calling `#flush` shouldn't be necessary in this use case. When a `Writer` (or the `OutputStream` behind it) is buffered for performance, the buffer has a reasonably low size limit anyway (dozen of kilobytes or such), after which it will flushes automatically. If the output is buffered for some functional reason, for example, to ensure that the output can be fully rolled back at any point, or so that the output can be returned as a single `String`, then that's something you should fix anyway (and that's where `#flush` is possibly ignored too). So, try to put a break point on `freemarker.template.Template.createProcessingEnvironment` and inspect the `out` `Writer` argument in the debugger (and the `Writer`/`OutputStream` that said `Writer` writes into, etc.). Maybe there will be `StringWriter` somewhere.

Comment: Digging into the Struts code I found the problem, my `FreemarkerManager` is using `TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER` and in Struts implementation (`FreemarkerResult`) this cause the writer to be flushed only _at the end_ of the template processing. @ddekany : do you know if is there a way to change the `TemplateExceptionHandler` for a single request?

Comment: Where's the logic that delays flushing if `RETHROW_HANDLER` is used? In Struts? Why's explicit flushing needed at all (see my answer above)? Otherwise, yes, you can call `Environment.setTemplateExceptionHandler` to change it for a single template processing, though I'm not sure where in Struts do you have opportunity to call that.

Comment: OK, I have looked at the Struts source code... indeed, with `RETHROW_HANDLER` it doesn't pass the actual `Writer` to FreeMarker, instead it collects everything into a `CharArrayWriter`, so flushing will do nothing. `Environment.setTemplateExceptionHandler` is useless for you, because the logic there only looks at the global `Configuration`. And I see no point where you could hook in...

Comment: BTW, the official way of making a particular template to use different configuration settings than the others is via the `template_configurations` configuration setting (since 2.3.24). With that you can declare in the FreeMarker configuration that `huge-output.ftl` uses another `TempalteExceptionHandler`. Unfortunately, as Struts (incorrectly) calls `Configuration.getTemplateExceptionHandler` instead of `Template.getTemplateExceptionHandler `, that won't help either...

Comment: Correct, as I mentioned in my answer Struts FreemarkerResult is kind of rigid and does not let you switch from a buffer-behaviour to a flush-behaviour in the way I wish. I proposed a patch for Struts here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4749